# Is there a way of specifying which argument QuTiP's parallel_map should iterate over?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parameter-passing, qutip

QuTiP's function [`parallel_map`](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html#qutip.parallel.parallel_map) provides the possibility to compute the value of a given function for several values of its argument in parallel. All the [examples](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/guide/guide-parfor.html#parallel-map-and-parallel-for-loop) show cases where the first positional argument is varied, like the following:

```
def testFunc1(a, b):
    return a, b

from qutip import parallel_map
parallel_map(testFunc1, (1, 2, 3), task_args=(4,))
```

This returns `[(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]`. Now I'm wondering if it's also possible to have a fixed value for `a` and a tuple for `b`. According to the [documentation](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html#qutip.parallel.parallel_map) `task_args` can also be a dictionary, so I tried

```
parallel_map(testFunc1, (1, 2, 3), task_args={'a': 4})
parallel_map(testFunc1, (1, 2, 3), task_args={'a': 4, 'b': (1, 2, 3)})
```

but this results in `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "dict") to tuple`. 
When I try

```
parallel_map(testFunc1, b=(1, 2, 3), task_args={'a': 4})
```

I get `TypeError: parallel_map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'`.

Does somebody know how to use `parallel_map` for the *n*-th positional argument (without writing a function wrapper for each *n*)?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"how to use **`parallel_map`** for the `n`-th positional argument <sub>(w/o writing a function wrapper for each `n`)</sub>?"*

Avoid creating problems, where they are not, and place whatever your `n`-th placed externally filled iterable in your `def`-ed function call-signature right into the `parallel_map()`-expected ( as documented ) and iteration-processing compliant **`tuple`** :

```
#          (           )-------------------------- parallel_map() expected TUPLE
#your Fun( (  a    vv--)-------------------)----------------your FED-IN ITERABLE
testFunc1( ( 'a', 'b1' ), 'of-no-interest' ) --> (('a', 'b1'), 'of-no-interest')
testFunc1( ( 'a', 'b2' ), 'of-no-interest' ) --> (('a', 'b2'), 'of-no-interest')
testFunc1( ( 'a', 'b3' ), 'of-no-interest' ) --> (('a', 'b2'), 'of-no-interest')
```

> <sub>*"Do you mean something like `parallel_map(testFunc1, [(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)], task_args=('of-no-interest',))`? Here `b` always has the value `'of-no-interest'`. – [A. P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9406722/a-p) [2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788669/is-there-a-way-of-specifying-which-argument-qutips-parallel-map-should-iterate/60789178?noredirect=1#comment107551779_60789178)"*</sub>

No,
the example is a clear path to **unload `a`** and any and all ***n*-th** user-side code FED-IN **iterable**(*s)*, right as was required above.

```
def testFun2( a, b ):
    return [ item for item in tuple( a ) ], b
```

show the way, a call to :

```
testFun2( ( 'a', 'b', "c", None, 42, -3.14159, "The-N-th-ITERABLE" ),
          'not-important-one-(of-no-interest-HERE-in-solving-N-th-iterable-for-parallel_star()-calls)...'
           )
```

delivers -->

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', None, 42, -3.14159, "The-N-th-ITERABLE"], 'not-important-one-(of-no-interest-HERE-in-solving-N-th-iterable-for-parallel_star()-calls)...')
```

**Exactly meeting both** ***a)*** your wish to have free-hands for any N-th iterable, not just the first positional one and also the  ***b)*** the very what the call-signature of the [**`parallel_map()`**](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html#qutip.parallel.parallel_map) expects and was documented to do so :

```
parallel_map( testFun2,                                        # TASK         Callable
              ( <_USER-SIDE_GENERATOR_FEED-IN_TUPLEsOfPARs_> ),# TASK VALUE(s)Array / List
              any_other_wished2have_call-signature_parameters, # TASK_ARGS    Dict
              ...,                                             # TASK_KWARGS  Dict
              ...                                              # call  KWARGS Dict
              )
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `parallel_map(testFunc1, [(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)], task_args=('of-no-interest',))`? Here `b` always has the value `'of-no-interest'`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. If I call `parallel_map(testFun2, ('a', 'b', "c", None, 42, -3.14159, "The-N-th-ITERABLE"), task_args=('long string',))` the value of `b` still is the same in all instances of `testFun2`. Could you please give an example of how `<_USER-SIDE_GENERATOR_FEED-IN_TUPLEsOfPARs_>` and `any_other_wished2have_call-signature_parameters` look like if the second argument of `testFun2` is varied between the parallel instances?

Comment: You miss the step of unloading the **b** ( being the any N-th iterable ) from the tuple, where it was put by the externally operated generator, not from a fixed position ( where it was not put by the caller ). Using a fixed-place argument **tuple**-as-a-payload-container is a common trick to meet the documented call-signature. Put all your iterated and non-iterated parameters positioned into a transfer-container ( yes, the **tuple** ( a list would the same ) ) and work this way to exactly meet the given QuTiP's interface.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it right you recommend to write the function with only 1 argument, which is an iterable containing `a` and `b`. The function then unpacks the individual arguments from it. To use `parallel_map` I would then use an iterable of these containers with different values for the variable which is unpacked into `b`. So basically `def testFunc3(c): return c(1), c(2)` and then calling `parallel_map(testFunc3, ((4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)))`?

Comment: Yes, this was **exactly what you wanted to get** - so as to get the wished to have freedom to inject *not a first, but* the ***N***-th iterable, to get passed to a call-signature, where but the first parameter receives an externally fed iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [source code of `parallel_map`](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/modules/qutip/parallel.html#parallel_map) reveals why it only works for the first argument of a function:

```
async_res = [pool.apply_async(task, (value,) + task_args, task_kwargs, _update_progress_bar)
             for value in values]
```

In this line the parallel processes are created. The function `task` gets a tuple representing all positional arguments, which is created from 1 element of the `values` and all the other `task_args`. Since the element of `values` is at the first position of the combined tuple (`(value,) + task_args`) it is *always the first argument* of the function which varies between its parallel instances. The `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "dict") to tuple` if a dictionary is used for `task_args` comes from the fact that the `+`-operator is only overloaded for `(tuple, tuple)`, not for `(tuple, dict)`.

So in the end there is no way around building a wrapper. Either one for each particular *n* or a generic one like:

```
def wrapper(varyingArgument, moreArgs):
    n = moreArgs[0]
    orderedArgs = moreArgs[1:n] + (varyingArgument,) + moreArgs[n:]
    return testFunc1(*orderedArgs)
```

Calling this with

```
parallel_map(wrapper, (1,2,3), task_args=((2, 4),))
```

returns

```
[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Comment: This was **obvious since the very beginning**, wasn't it?

Comment: If I had dug into the documentation right from the start I could have answered my question right away. But it's nevertheless interesting to see if someone finds a more elegant solution.